# Cannot Import kivy on Spyder

Tags: python, kivy, spyder

- I am using Python37, Kivy 1.11.1, and Spyder3
- I am unable to import kivy as a module
- I followed these instructions exactly, and set up a venv for it as suggested
- The file for the Python script is saved within the venv that contains kivy
- Here is the code run: `import kivy`
- And the error code, in full is:

  ```
  runfile('C:/Users/Liam/kivy_venv/CL_APP.py', wdir='C:/Users/Liam/kivy_venv')
  Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<ipython-input-10-99293c9bbf5a>", line 1, in <module>
      runfile('C:/Users/Liam/kivy_venv/CL_APP.py', wdir='C:/Users/Liam/kivy_venv')

    File "C:\Users\Liam\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
      execfile(filename, namespace)

    File "C:\Users\Liam\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
      exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

    File "C:/Users/Liam/kivy_venv/CL_APP.py", line 8, in <module>
      import kivy

  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'
  ```

The executed code.

Lower right is the error code recieved.

[image]

If I am leaving out anything important please let me know. I assume I am just rusty and don't know how to import modules correctly and its likely an issue with where kivy is saved in my computer compared to where the Python script is.

Separate question and possible hint, I only have Python37 installed but the IDE says, in the top left corner, that it is Python 3.6. Could this cause an issue with this or anything else?

Thank you.

Comment: According to the error message you are using Anaconda3, are you sure you have kivy installed in Anaconda3?

Comment: I am fairly certain i do not, how does one do that? do i just move the dependencies and kivy over to my Anaconda3 file? @eyllanesc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was there was an issue with my Anaconda files, i uninstalled and re-downloaded Anaconda and then use the anaconda prompt to download kivy and that fixed my problems.

EDIT:
there was issues with my anaconda files, however if one were to need to install Kivy on their device and also use Spyder on Anaconda as their IDE, all one needs to do is locate their Anaconda Prompt, found somewhere like `C:\Program Files\Anaconda\bin\Anaconda.exe`, I do not have Anaconda installed and am not certain of that path.

Once in the anaconda prompt run:

```
conda install kivy=x.x.x
```